# Printing Pattern with Nested for Loops in C

Tags: c

I'm studying for an exam and the professor asked for a program that can print out the following patterns: [picture of the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z4OW.png)

```
N=2    N=3    N=4    N=5
**     ***    ****   *****
 **     ***    ****   *****
       ***    ****   *****
               ****   *****
                     *****
```

(Except the image misses the fifth line for `N=5`.)

My program can get a similar output except it doubles the number of rows for each expected output (IE when N=3 there are 6 rows, when N=4 there are 8 rows). Not sure how to stop it running after the number of rows hits N. Here's my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int N, rows1, width1, rows2, width2;

    printf("Please enter a number between 2 and 5 (including 2 and 5).\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    if (N<2 || N>5)
    {
        printf ("The number you entered is either less than 2 or greater than 5."
                " Please try again.\n");
                return 0;
    }

    for (rows1=1; rows1<=N; rows1++)
    {
        for(width1=1; width1<=N; width1++)
            printf ("*");
        printf ("\n");

        for(rows2=1; rows2<=1; rows2++)
            printf (" ");

        for(width2=1; width2<=N; width2++)
            printf ("*");
        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should `N = 5` have 5 rows?

Comment: There's no reason to post that output as a picture since it is only text. Please convert it to text.

Comment: `for(rows2=1; rows2<=1; rows2++)` is useless. I guess you're supposed to loop twice on the number of elements, on for vertical, one for horizontal, and add a space only on odd lines (%2 == 1) if counted from 0

Comment: You could start by removing `rows2` and `width2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In the first conditional, you return 0 to indicate a success.  I would go with the macro EXIT_FAILURE (even better use a while loop until you get a valid input from the user) in the conditional obtaining the user's input.

2) I would trace through this and see step by step what you expect to get at each step in your program.  Think about if you could eliminate some of the for loops, how many are really essential for your program to run?

*************ONLY LOOK AT THIS WHEN YOU HAVE ATTEMPTED FIXING IT YOURSELF ***********

```
int main() {

        int N;

        printf("Please enter a number between 2 and 5 (including 2 and 5). \n");
        scanf("%d", &N);

        if (N<2 || N>5)
        {
            printf ("The number you entered is either less than 2 or greater than 5. \
            Please try again.");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        for (int length= 0; length < N; length++) {
            if(length %2 == 1){
                    printf(" ");
            }
            for(int width = 0; width < N; width++) {

                printf("*");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: most likely missing the " " to add every 2 lines!

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was intentional or not in the picture.

Comment: Sure. As is the question of 4 or 5 lines in the case 5, not likely correct in the picture!

Comment: I added the line in there

Comment: The `if` statement is saying that if the `width` is equal to zero and the length has a remainder of one after being divided by two, meaning an odd number, then print a space, right?  Is because the first line of the program will be considered zero and the second line will be considered one (odd)?

Comment: Thank you @mdfst13 for the catch.  I deleted the comment about O(n^4)

Comment: @mdfst13 I also moved the space before the inner loop. Thank you.  Feel free to edit my answer as well.

Comment: @Rozay Yes is the mod operator and works basically as you describe.  The odd numbered rows have a space before the * get printed out.  It does not happen on every execution thus the need for a conditional (if).  I updated the answer based upon feedback from mdfst13 so please take another look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You print twice in your outer loop.  I.e. you have

```
for 1 to N, stepping by 1
    print line

    print leading space
    print line
```

So you print two times `N` lines when you want to print exactly `N` lines.

Either increase your increment (replace `rows++` with `rows += 2` which will cause you to only print an even number of lines, so you'll have to fix it for odd `N`) or change to print only one line per iteration (where you'll have to fix the alternating leading space).  [The @malanb5 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54777058/6660678) codes an example of the latter solution.